# How to build a docker image with PHP-fpm and nginx using docker-compose

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to deploy my dockerized application using docker-compose. I have  an `application` service running with `php-fpm` and an nginx service running with the latest nginx image. Now I would like to build an image that can run my PHP application using Nginx. I'm not sure how to accomplish that. I have seen some images that are pre build for it, but nothing seemed promising.

Would the correct way to do it be to install nginx on a php based imaged and use that? I'm not sure.

```
version: "3"
 services:

   application:
     networks:
      - mynetwork
   container_name: the-application
   image: the-application:latest
   build:
     context: ./
   dockerfile: ./docker/application.dockerfile
   volumes:
     - ./backend/:/backend

   backend-server:
     container_name: the-backend-server
     image: the-backend-server:latest
     build:
       context: ./
       dockerfile: ./docker/server.dockerfile
     volumes:
       - ./backend/:/backend
       - ./configs/nginx/nginx.backend-prod.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
     ports:
       - 80:80
     networks:
       - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
```

Comment: I'd suggest looking into some examples, like [this one](https://github.com/nanoninja/docker-nginx-php-mysql/blob/master/docker-compose.yml). With docker compose you're basically building a recipe for a collection of containers and how they will be linked together. So you can just pick and choose the web server you want, the db server you want, caching, etc and build your app infrastructure.

Comment: Do you want both nginx & php-fpm running in same container OR both as different services/containers will do? @jonas

Comment: I was hoping to have them run in the same container. But is that even good practice? I think I would be able to run both using a script but not sure if that's too dirty.

Comment: No, not a good practice. One container = one process. You could use official images for php and nginx.